# CannotPullContainerError from public fargate service after creating ECR vpc endpoint with private dns names enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

In order to get Fargate services in private subnets to work, I created an ECR vpc endpoint, a S3 gateway endpoint and a logs vpc endpoint.

However, after creating the ECR endpoint my service in the public subnet could no longer pull containers: `CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon`

The service in the public subnet has Auto-assign public IP ENABLED.

*If I turn private dns names enabled off for the ECR endpoint, the public service will run again, but now the services in the private subnet can't pull their container...*

What am I missing?

Comment: Worth checking this blog, if you haven't already.  There are quite a few endpoints you need to enable - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr/

Comment: I did read it. The launch type for the services is fargate, so as far as I can tell from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html I should only have to enable com.amazonaws.region.ecr.dkr Amazon ECR VPC endpoint and the Amazon S3 gateway endpoint...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by implementing it as follows:

**vpc.tf**

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  create_vpc = var.create_vpc

  // other config ...

  enable_s3_endpoint = true

  enable_ecr_dkr_endpoint              = true
  ecr_dkr_endpoint_private_dns_enabled = true
  ecr_dkr_endpoint_security_group_ids  = aws_security_group.vpc_endpoints.*.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "vpc_endpoints" {
  count = var.create_vpc ? 1 : 0

  name   = "PrivateLink endpoints security group"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_https" {
  count = var.create_vpc ? 1 : 0

  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 443
  to_port     = 443
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = [module.vpc.private_subnets_cidr_blocks]

  description       = "HTTPS access to VPC Endpoints"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.vpc_endpoints[0].id
}
```

**ecs-security-groups.tf**

```
variable "private_subnets_cidr_blocks" {}

resource "aws_security_group" "ecs" {
  count       = var.create ? 1 : 0
  name        = "${var.name}-ecs"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_https_vpc" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  type        = "egress"
  from_port   = 443
  to_port     = 443
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = var.private_subnets_cidr_blocks

  description       = "HTTPS access to VPC Endpoints"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ecs[0].id
}
```

For reference, I got the `CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon` you mentioned above when my security groups on both the Endpoints and the ECS Service were not configured to allow `HTTPS` traffic between them

HTH